# getting push notifications to appear in devices status bar

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, phonegap-plugins

I currently have a phonegap app where I'm using pushPlugin and the alert box to show incoming push notifications. However, i'd like for those messages to appear in the devices status bar. Is there something extra I need to do to make them appear there; Perhaps some additional configuration? Thanks.

Here is that section of code using the alert box:

```
 case 'message':
      // if this flag is set, this notification happened while we were in the foreground.
      // you might want to play a sound to get the user's attention, throw up a dialog, etc.
      if (event.foreground) {
            console.log('INLINE NOTIFICATION');
            //var my_media = new Media("/android_asset/www/" + event.soundname);
            //my_media.play();
      } else {
        if (event.coldstart) {
            console.log('COLDSTART NOTIFICATION');
        } else {
            console.log('BACKGROUND NOTIFICATION');
        }
      }

      navigator.notification.alert(event.payload.message);//alert notification
      console.log('MESSAGE -> MSG: ' + event.payload.message);
      //Only works for GCM
      console.log('MESSAGE -> MSGCNT: ' + event.payload.msgcnt);
      //Only works on Amazon Fire OS
      console.log('MESSAGE -> TIME: ' + event.payload.timeStamp);
      break;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is doing a local notification, and you can implement that easily with a local notification plugin. The WizCorp plugin at https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-plugin-localNotifications is a good one, so add that to your project:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/Wizcorp/phonegap-plugin-localNotifications.git
```

and in your code replace this:

```
navigator.notification.alert(event.payload.message);//alert notification
```

with this:

```
localNotification.add(1, {message: event.payload.message}); //local notification
```

to add the message text to the device's list of notifications, which are displayed in the status bar and in the notifications tray.